# swift difference between final var and non-final var | final let and non-final let

Tags: swift, swift2

What's difference between final variables and non-final variables :

```
var someVar = 5
final var someFinalVar = 5
```

and

```
let someLet = 5
final let someFinalLet = 5
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `final` modifier is described in the [Swift Language Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html), which says

> **final**
>
> Apply this modifier to a class or to a property, method, or subscript member of a class. It’s applied to a class to indicate that the class can’t be subclassed. It’s applied to a property, method, or subscript of a class to indicate that a class member can’t be overridden in any subclass.

This means without `final` we can write:

```
class A {
    var x: Int {return 5}
}
class B : A {
    override var x: Int {return 3}
}
var b = B()
assert(b.x == 3)
```

but if we use `final` in class `A`

```
class A {
    final var x: Int {return 5}
}
class B : A {
    // COMPILER ERROR
    override var x: Int {return 3}
}
```

then this happens:

```
$ swift final.swift 
final.swift:6:18: error: var overrides a 'final' var
    override var x: Int {return 3}
             ^
final.swift:2:15: note: overridden declaration is here
    final var x: Int {return 5}
```

Answer (score 2):

Final variables can't be overridden in subclasses. It also hints this to the compiler which allows it to inline the variable. It other words every time the compiler sees a final variable being used somewhere, it can immediately substitute the value. Whether or not the compiler actually does this is up to the compiler and whatever optimisations it knows/uses.